# Не устанавливается приложение apk на телефон

Tags: android, установка, apk

Создал приложение в android studio, компилируется, подключенный телефон принимает его, все работает. Но если передаю apk файл другому телефону, он не устанавливает, так и на моем, удалил приложение, установил его через apk файл, он не устанавливает "приложение не установлено". Что требуется изменить в самой программе или где, чтоб устанавливалось?

Comment: как вы создаете apk?

Comment: В папке androidapps > build > outputs> apk нахожу просто файл apk.

Comment: Подпишите приложение

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего у вас не установлена опция "Установка из неизвестных источников".

Для Android начиная с 8 версии мы можем предоставить разрешение на установку приложений из неизвестных источников только для этого Приложения. Включаем разрешение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для более старых девайсов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько.

1. Если на телефоне уже стояло это приложение с другой подписью и его пытаются обновить, то ничего не выйдет. Надо удалить старое и ставить новое.
2. Запрещена установка из неизвестных источников. Хотя при попытке установки приложения система должна уведомить вас.
3. Попробуйте еще в AndroidStudio сделать Build->Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)->Build APK(s). После этого внизу появится сообщение об успешном билде и нажмите в нем locate. Откроется папка с APK файлом. Попробуйте его передать на смарт и запустить. Должно сработать.